# Infinite series specially partial sum of p-series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Can anyone show me how to deal with this limit question involving p-series? I would really be grateful.

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1{N^{\frac23}}\sum_{n=1}^Nn^{-p}=\begin{cases}
a,&\text{if }p=1\\
b,&\text{if }p=\frac13\\
c,&\text{if }p>\frac13\text{ and }p\ne 1\\
d,&\text{if }p<\frac13
\end{cases}$$

Find $a,b,c$, and $d$.